# How to find cause of server error 500 with code 222 in Zen Cart

Tags: zen-cart

We have [Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart) running on a Linux box and are trying to move it to another server. We get a server error 500 with the cryptic error message "number 222 from the VAT module".

What does this mean or how might we debug?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 usually means that there is an issue in the app's logic.  The VAT module would have to do with European taxes, I think.  I would look in that section of code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way in zne_cart to narrow it down to a specific file (debug log function so we can see which file it fails on)?

Comment: See this page:  http://www.question-defense.com/2009/03/21/zen-cart-error-debug-checkout-process-showing-a-blank-page